# Inset: remove white space

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to insert a ragged line on a plot axis by using an inset. However, I always get white space around the inset such that my axis is broken at some point. What can I do to remove the white space?

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, 
Epilog -> {{Inset[
 Style[
  Graphics[
   {Thickness[0.02],
    Line[{{-0.1,0},{0,0},{0.2,0.2},{0.6,-0.2},{1,0.2},{1.2,0},{1.3,0}}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 15], 
  Background -> White],
  {0.5, 0}]}},
  ImagePadding -> 15,PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use this whole `Inset[Style[Graphics[Line[...] ...]]]` and not just give the graphics directive directly in Epilog, like `Epilog -> {White, Rectangle[{0.475, -.1}, {.525, .1}], Black, Thickness[0.002], Line[...]}`?

Comment: There is no specific reason other than my limited knowledge about alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0` to the inner `Graphics` object.